# How can I show an xml file in my asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, response

In a .Net web-service, when you click "invoke" button an XML file is opened.

I have a page with a button. I want when I click it an XML page be opened like web-service pages. I have written the following code but it does not return an XML page. how can i do that?

1) I am in "http://mysite/default.aspx"

2) click my button

3) This page be opened with the .Xml extension: "http://mysite/result.xml"

```
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 //Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=result.xml");
 Response.AddHeader("content-type", "text/xml");
 Response.Write("aaaa");
 Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

It write the code `Response.Redirect("xmlfile.xml");` and it is showing xml as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a contenttype to your response.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";          
Response.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\">");
//whatever you want
Response.End();
```

PS.content-disposition will give you an "option" to download the file (the browser will download the file, not posting it to the browser itself);

```
Response.ContentType = "application/" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pathToFile).Substring(1).ToLower();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pathToFile)));
Response.WriteFile(pathToFile);
Response.End();
```

Comment: your sample code does not open a new window containing my file contents.

Comment: @breceivemail ofcourse it doesn't. Openening a new window for download is the second codesample. But opening an XML file in a new window is up to you (add a target to your anchor for instance).